# Ad blocker blocks Ajax call response html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

**I am rendering some stats on my page, as this takes a bit of time I made this request an ajax call after the page loads**

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(Routes.MyAds.AjxCallFoAbc, new {advertId = Model.CreateAdvertHeader.SelectedAdvert.Id})',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('.advert-performance').replaceWith(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**This works perfectly for me, its causing grief when the user installs a ad-blocker, this content is being blocked, I have debugged the code-base and found the ajax call route is never being hit when the ad-blocker is enabled on the browser**

[image: the ad blocker snippet]

> What is the work-around for this, I need show the stats even if the ad-blocker is installed

Comment: This is the point of the ad blocker to prevent ajax data load, You may beable to register your site with the ad-blocking app and get added to the whitelist as your data is infact not an ad.

Comment: but the content that I am showing are not even ads, they are part of the main content of the page, I want to know how they determine which is an ad is it everything that is loaded with an ajax call is considered an ad??

Comment: Which ad blocker(s) is causing this?

Comment: Just a guess...you have the word "ads" and "adverts" (4x) in your code and URL. AdBlock is probably making an assumption. Try naming it something else.

Answer (score 2):

**Resolved it**

> The reason being, my route which the ajax was pointed to had a **advert-stats** as part of the url, which caused the blocker to block it,
>   simply changing the route has fixed it

[image: Route changes]